# Functions defined on a object within a prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define functions on a object within a prototype like in this example:

```
function Particle = {
  this.calculate.x = 0;
}

Particle.prototype.calculate.calculateX = function() {
   //do calculation
}

var particle - new Particle();
```

If I explore particle in the browser console the 'calculate' object is visible but without any of the functions defined on it.

What am I missing?
Is it even possible to define an object prototype in this way?

Cheers!

Comment: I bet you get some syntax errors... fix them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function Particle() {
  this.calculate.x = 0;
}

Particle.prototype.calculate = {
    calculateX: function() {
        //do calculation
    }
}

var particle = new Particle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining `calculate` on the prototype at all by accessing `this.calculate` within the constructor. Infact your syntax is entirely wrong there..

```
function Particle = {
};
```

should be

```
function Particle() {
}
```

Accessing `this` within the constructor function just writes stuff into that instance object, not on its `.prototype`.